# Sliding swipe panel for mobile with sliding side menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm having a hard time finding some jQuery or JavaScript to do the following:
btw - I'm using ReactJS but any of the swipe / swipeable NPM modules are still missing features.

My wishlist, this is for a mobile phone & tablet app:

1. Swipeable panels like Tinder, Snapchat. Must also be programmable so they can be selected from a side menu, see #2 below. I'm currently using swipeJS: https://github.com/thebird/Swipe It's working OK, but the slide(index, duration) doesn't change duration values. And not sure how to get this working with a Side menu that is also swipe to close.
2. Side menu, must also be swipeable to close it -- the jQuery examples I've seen here only close on a click, not a swipe: http://www.jqueryscript.net

Update: this closes on swipe: http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/App-Style-Fly-out-Navigation-Menu-Plugin-For-jQuery-iosmenu.html

3. The swipeable panel must be able to set an area that is NOT affected by the main page swipes, why? I want to do something like Tinder, but instead of people I will have a game that uses swipe, like Angry Birds. Yet still want to be able to swipe outside of the game area to move between main panels/pages. Note, my game will not be full screen.

I'm wondering if this is all too much for an HTML mobile app (will wrap it with Cordova or PhoneGap), and if I should go native. But I'm hoping to leverage HTML, and ReactJS.

Comment: Hi! were you able to get through this ? I am also struggling with somewhat similar problem, I just need page transition with sliding animation something like this : http://coenraets.org/samples/pageslider/index.html. I tried ReactCSSTransition but it doesnt work with phonegap. detail description : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297658/how-to-make-reactcsstransitiongroup-work-in-phonegap
any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: I hacked my own solution together. You may also want to try: react-swipe: https://github.com/jed/react-swipe

Comment: FrameWork7 also looks interesting: http://www.idangero.us/framework7/#.Vi-E12RVhBc